# How can a jquery button have newline?

Tags: jquery-ui, button, newline

I was wondering how to allow jquery ui button to allow newline.

Before turning to jquery button.

```
<input type="button" id="btnFX" value="Button Name
With 
New Line" />
```

turning to jquery button

```
$('#btnF9').removeAttr('disabled');
$('#btnF9').button();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's nothing to do with jQuery really:

```
<button type="button" id="btnFX" >Button Name<br />With<br />New Line</button>
<script> 
    $(function() {
        $("#btnFX").button();
    });
</script>
```